# Laravel project not working after successfully installation on the server

Tags: php, laravel-5, server

I have successfully installed **Laravel** project on the server but its not working. I am getting error like "page isn’t working

> HTTP ERROR 500".

I have execute command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel
```

and created a directory name Laravel. But it's not working while same thing I have done on my local server and it's working fine.

Comment: Try checking PHP version and also error_log.

Comment: url rewrite! may be

Answer (score 0):

I run composer update and it resolve the problem. Known I run the following command from the root path of the application:

It was not the .htaccess file that was the problem nor the index.php. The problem was on accessing the files and requiring permissions.

For solving the problem i ran the following commands through terminal.

```
sudo chmod 755 -R laravel_blog
```

and then type below to allow laravel to write file to storage folder

```
chmod -R o+w laravel_blog/storage
```

This two commands solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Should I use super admin login to run this command? because I have run this command and still not working. I have not access of super admin.

Answer (score 0):

in local you serve laravel project by internal web server using below command:
   php artisan serve

but in your server env you must use apache conf and you must set document root like this: 
your_project_directory/public/index.php

if every thing ok till now, your error must made by laravel error handling.
if so, then you can check your laravel log to find out exactly 500 error reason:

go to your project directory, then navigate to storage directory, here is logs directory and it has a laravel.log

tail -f your_project_directory/storage/logs/laravel.log

your generated log are here so read and solve it :)

tips: you must set privilages to your storage directory in server.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have checked in storage/logs and there is no any logs file laravel.log" in that directory.

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 app/storage after run this command laravel genrate laravel.log and fill it by errors.

Comment: also you can change the group to your webserver user, supposing it's www-data:

chown -R vagrant:www-data app/storage

Answer (score 0):

Please insert below command and try to access.

```
setenforce 0
```

it's working for me.